# Unable to insert Image CKEditor(Decoupled Editor), Giving error even after providing uploadUrl in ckfinder

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor5

I am using ckFinder -> uploadUrl, still getting error as alert message that "Cannot upload this image". What can be the right solution to it ?

```
DecoupledEditor.create(document.querySelector('#NewsLetters_editor'), {
            ckfinder: {
                uploadUrl: '/Community/NewsLetter/NewsletterImageServcie.asmx/UploadImage?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json'
            }
        }).then(editor => {

        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
import DecoupledEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document/src/ckeditor';
    DecoupledEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('.document-editor__editable'), {
            cloudServices: {
        }
        })
        .then(editor => {
            const toolbarContainer = document.querySelector('.document-editor__toolbar');

            toolbarContainer.appendChild(editor.ui.view.toolbar.element);

            window.editor = editor;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
```

I think this one helps you.